# Finding diagonal of Convex Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

I know length of a convex quadrilateral's four sides, and one diagonal.
Then, how to calculate the other diagonal's length?
Here's an example.(Looking for BD)

Convex Quadrilateral

[image: Convex Quadrilateral]

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Using the theorem of cosines we obtain
$$BD^2=a^2+d^2-2ad\cos(\alpha)$$

Comment: Is there no way to find diagonal with no angles?

Comment: What is given in that problem?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula

Comment: Just lengths are given. Exactly, I want generalized formula with just length (I'll do chain-calculation with formula)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the four sides and a diagonal (e.g.$AC$) then you know the area by applying the [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to the two triangles.
Then applying the same formula to the two triangles with the unknown diagonal in common, you can solve for that.